# Why is ~/Documents a symlink to itself, and how should this be fixed?

Tags: symlink

I'm a programmer diagnosing a customer's issue with our software. We're having some problems writing into the user's `Documents` folder in macOS Mojave 10.14.6.*

It turns out that the customer's `~/Documents` folder is a symlink *to itself*, causing `ELOOP` errors when calling file APIs, and a `Too many levels of symbolic links` error when attempting to view its contents in the Terminal with the `ls` command.

[image: Terminal output]

However, in the Finder, the folder displays normally, and appears to contain 15GB of contents.

[image]

The first time we saw this issue I wrote it off as an unsolved mystery, but this is the second customer we have seen in the past few years with a Documents folder that is a symbolic link to itself.

So my questions are:

1. How is this possible?
2. What can cause this configuration? Is there any legitimate reason it might be configured this way?
3. Is it safe to tell the user just to move all the contents somewhere safe, delete the folder, and then recreate it in the Finder?

<sub>* The path is obtained by passing `NSDocumentDirectory` into `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomain`.</sub>

Comment: @klanomath Whoops. Edited question to include the version. (It's Mojave). The software is in no way connected to dev/coding, and the customer isn't a developer.

Comment: I would ask the customer to run the following commands: `find -L $HOME/Documents -type l` and `diskutil verifyVolume /` and send the output of the two commands back to you. *(delete comment/edit reason: first `find` command was wrong)*

Comment: @klanomath Thanks for the suggestions. What are you looking for in the output of the two commands?

Comment: @klanomath I've read the man pages, so I know what they _do_. Just not sure how they'll help?

Comment: Reason1: Dropbox hack/linking external Documents folder to $HOME went wrong. Reason2: simply a file system error.

Comment: What happens if the Documents folder is dragged and dropped into a Terminal window?  This pastes the path of the folder into the command line.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen As well as the recursive `Documents` symlink, the customer also has a folder named `Documents<Space>` which contained all their actual files. The difference wasn't visible in the Finder, but dragging it into the Terminal inserted a backslash escape, solving the mystery. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is this possible?

It's easy to mess up when using `ln` on the command line. A symlink to self is legal (though nonsensical) so you wouldn't get an error when creating it.

> What can cause this configuration? Is there any legitimate reason it might be configured this way?

It's useless and should be removed. Once removed, they can create a new `~/Documents/` folder. If you're concerned about safety, keep in mind you can always drag things back from the trash.

> Is it safe to tell the user just to move all the contents somewhere safe, delete the folder, and then recreate it in the Finder?

If it's a symlink to self then it has no contents, because it's just a self-referential symlink. It's not a folder, it's just a recursive symlink. Finder is showing some folder that's named `Documents` but that doesn't mean it's showing `~/Documents/`. You could create a folder with that name anywhere and add it to the Finder sidebar.

It would probably help to ask the user to cmd-click on the folder name at the top of the Finder window. That will show where it's located:

[image: Finder "Documents" window showing full folder path]

Comment: This answer would be quite encouraging, except the folder they’ve sent me screenshots of isn’t some random Documents folder they’ve added to the sidebar. It is `/Users/[username]/Documents`, and Finder does indeed report that it has contents, even though commands I’ve asked them to run in the terminal disagree.

Comment: Then you're missing some crucial detail(s). A directory and a symbolic link are two different things; a directory cannot also be a symlink, even to itself. A symbolic link can point to a directory, but then it's a symbolic link and not a directory.

Comment: The terminal reports it is a symbolic link that points to itself. The Finder displays it as a folder with contents. (See the screenshots I just added to the question). I don't understand how this is possible, and this is the main reason I asked my question.

Comment: You were right. The folder the customer was sending us screenshots of was indeed a completely different Folder. Specifically, it was one named `Documents<Space>`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah, spaces in the name. Tricksy.